# Searching text file in Unix using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I have an input text file (shown below) which I have to call in a shell script and also in shell script I will pass an input argument for which I have find a corresponding value from the input text file.

So if my input argument is `Janan` I have to return `Janan_2` as output, or if my input is `Janan_ex1` then output will be `Janan_loc_data`.

Input:

```
"data":"{\"collection\":{\n    \"Janan\":\"Janan_2\",\n    \"Janan_ex1\":\"Janan_loc_data\",\n    \"Neha\":\"Neha_1\",\n    \"cric\":\"cric_2\",\n    \"San\":\"San_1\",\n    \"Arp\":\"Arp_1\",\n    \"Nipun_test4\":\"Nipun_test3\",\n    \"tran_Nipun\":\"tran_Nipun_2\",\n    \"Zing\":\"Zing_1\"}}"}
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus ..this link seems more on HTML tag and stuff .. I need some help in Shell scripting..which i am not much familiar with specially AWK

Comment: If you're parsing JSON data then use jq in unix shells

Comment: Anubhava can you please share an example if you have something handy

Comment: Is your input data really on one line?  Does it really contain all the backslashes?  Is it really JSON-encoded data, with the collection as a string value instead of a regular JSON object enclosed in `{ … }`?  That's just brutal.

Comment: Jonathan ..i am getting this line with grep command and I get this file from some other department in exact same format.

Comment: I cannot use jq as it is not available/installed at our machine servers

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your input "file" into the following bash script with your "input argument" as the argument, e.g. `...|./bashscript San`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sed 's/[^ ]*// ; s/}}"}// ; s/"://g ; s/,\\n/\n/g'|
tr -d '\\'|
awk -F\" '$2=="'$1'"{print $3}'
```